# Cron Jobs are scheduled but not running; new order Emails not executing, all data export is stucking

Tags: cron, magento-1.9.2.0

I am new to magento. I have little knowledge in unix also.

New order emails are not going, notify via email is not working but rest are for shipping, cancellation order are working.

Exporting all products data profile is not working; it was stuck on screen displaying "do not close the window"..

I have checked backpanel settings for cron jobs, it was:

Generate Schedules Every - 15
Schedule Ahead for - 45
Missed if Not Run Within - 45
History Cleanup Every - 10
Success History Lifetime - 60
Failure History Lifetime - 600

also I have checked Cpanel for cron jobs it was:

*/15    *   *   *   *   wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.doorstepmarket.com/cron.php > /dev/null8,17,36,54 * * * * php /home/doorsg6t/public_html/doorstep/cron.php > /dev/null

I have no idea where is the issue, need help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen if other operation are taking it's place?

I use AEO Scheduler to manage about 40 Cron jobs. It's just easier to see with a nice GUI. If Cron has been called on 1 node for that server for cron they will have to wait until the next pass. If you executed a large file, like exporting, based on the amount of data it could take some time. Sometimes over 60-120 minutes.

The AEO Scheduler will let you know all the Crons that you are currently running off your Magento Cron.php(or Cron.sh). If you are experienced and understand each module place in 'your world of Magento' you can also work with the Cron times to try to prevent conflicts as well.

Play around with that and if you have anymore questions feel free to let me know, but it's likely 1 of the 2 issues.